# How do you change the logging level in Apache Tomcat and reduce the size of catalina.out

Tags: log4j

I am using pusher chat application.
In pusher i am using webhook client events for chatting using presence channel.
So the problem is whenever users are chatting my webhook api gets called and the logs are coming that frequently. I want to stop this logs. the problem is beacause of this logs my file catalina.out is increasing its size and proportionately my server size is getting increased.

To stope httpclieny i have used below line in log4j prop file

```
log4j.logger.httpclient=WARN
```

So same way i want to know for the solution for pusher.

Thanks.